# FSL installs on Ubuntu 22.10, but no FSL function is available

Tags: software-installation, python

I tried installing FMRIB's FSL toolkit on Ubuntu 22.10. The downloaded fslinstaller.py runs absolutely fine without any errors, and clears both stages. It selects /usr/local/fsl as the default install directory. However, when trying to use FSL it is not detected. For instance, `echo $FSLDIR` returns nothing.I mean it literally returns an empty line. Anything else, including flirt -version and fsleyes simply returns a "not installed" message.

I couldn't find any record of this specific issue, so I figured asking here might help. If anybody has any ideas, you have my advanced gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a bit of poking around I figured out what the problem was. It appears that you have to relog the shell every time you close your terminal window.

I have to redo the source `~./bash_profile` command to get FSL up and running every time.

EDIT (Jan, 8, 2023):

This issue of having to relog the shell after exiting terminal has disappeared on its own with [the latest version of FSL](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation). Simply download the new installer and update FSL.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, my FSLDIR is `/usr/local/fsl`. You could verify if it is the same for you and add

`export FSLDIR=/usr/local/fsl`

to your .bashrc or .bash_profile (supposing you're using linux).

See here. https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/ShellSetup

Comment: Yeah, the folder was always there, but I was still getting the error. Turns out, every time I close the terminal, I need to relog the shell again to get FSL up and running. Do you have to do this too?